# MVVM Light messenger only works if I manually instantiate viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I'm sure there is only some little tiny detail I am missing . Using MVVM light, I am simply trying to send a simple message from one view to another view ( actually to another view model) . It only works if i **instantiate** the receiving viewmodel first, otherwise it doesnt'.

1- I created a blank WPF application and added MVVM light using nuget and it added its own bits of codes as it usually does.

2- All I have added is below

In Code behind of MainWindow.xaml ( Ignore that i am not using a relaycommand here for now, I just need the Messenger to work)

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //If I don't put the line below to create a new model, the  
            //message box in the next code piece isn't shown at all
            ReceiverViewModel rec=new ReceiverViewModel();
            Messenger.Default.Send("Hello, can you see me?");
        }
```

This is the receiving viewmodel

```
public ReceiverViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<String>(this, x =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x);
            });
        }
```

This is the auto-generated ViewModel locator ( I added the receiver viewmodel myself)

```
 public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ReceiverViewModel>();
        }

        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
    }
```

Where do I need to initialize the `receiving viewmodel` so i can remove the line above?

Thanks

Comment: If you do not initialize it first nothing will be listening for messages so sent message will vanish without a trace.

Comment: So if I have 20 different Viewmodels , for each I will have to manually initialize everyone?

Comment: It depends whether all of them are supposed to listen to messages. If so yes you do. Otherwise you can initialize them whenever you wish. Think how not yet created ViewModel can listen to messages? Messages are not queued.

Comment: ok , thx. My purpose was , whether there is a best practice/place for initializing a viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewModel must be exists to listen message
To instantiated viewmodel as you register it:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>(true);
```

Comment: This was exactly the little thing I thought I was missing, the (true) parameter was all I needed.thanks